# Declare variable Oracle in dataset SSRS

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I would like to know about declare variable in dataset SSRS data source oracle to get value from parameter.
I ever declare variable in dataset SSRS data source Microsoft SQL, but I'm not sure about Oracle's syntax.

For example syntax Microsoft Sql on dataset SSRS

```
DECLARE @product_id  int = @product_id_from_parameter

SELECT * FROM PRODUCT
WHERE PRODUCT_ID = @product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle , they dont use `@` to define variables, you can just remove it, also to assign value use `:=`. So try write it in this way:

```
DECLARE product_id  int := product_id_from_parameter;
begin
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT
WHERE PRODUCT_ID := product_id;
end;
/
```